# Implement UDF and Pig Script logic in Talend

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, talend, bigdata

I have written a UDF that reads an input file and segregates the Data into String and Integer or String and Double.

My UDF is working fine. Also I have written a Pig Script to use the above jar on HDFS.

Now I want to have this code integrated with Talend for Big Data.
How can I acheive this.

The java code in the UDF is below :

```
package com.test.udf;


import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.data.TupleFactory;

public class CheckDataType extends EvalFunc<Tuple> {

       @Override
       public Tuple exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              String valString = null;
              Integer valInt =  null;
              Double valDouble =null;
              String str = (String) input.get(0);

              Tuple outputTuple =TupleFactory.getInstance().newTuple(2);

              if (str != null){
                     try{
                           valInt = Integer.parseInt(str);
                           outputTuple.set(0, valString);
                           outputTuple.set(1, valInt);

                     }
                     catch(Exception e){
                           try{
                                  valDouble = Double.parseDouble(str) ;
                                  outputTuple.set(0, valString);
                                  outputTuple.set(1, valDouble);
                           }
                           catch(Exception ew){
                           outputTuple.set(0, str);
                           outputTuple.set(1, null);
                           }
                     }     

              }
              return outputTuple;

       }

}
```

Also The pig script I have written is below :

```
REGISTER 'CONVERT.jar';

data_load = LOAD '/tmp/input/testfile.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (col1:chararray, col2:chararray, col3:chararray, col4:chararray, col5:chararray);

data_grp = GROUP data_load BY ($input_col);

data_flatten = FOREACH data_grp GENERATE FLATTEN(com.test.udf.CheckDataType(*));

rmf /tmp/output;

STORE data_flatten INTO '/tmp/output' USING PigStorage(',');
```

How can I integrate this in Talend for Big Data.

Comment: There are Pig components in Talend. Have you had a look at the examples?

Comment: I have had a look at those. How Can I use this.

Comment: @user3454116 Do you tried to put the jar in the same server where your Talend job is deployed and register it using the full path ?

Comment: @54l3d: Can you please describe the flow of the components and the configuration so that i could check the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer:

You need to split your pig script into 3 components, PigLoad, PigCode and PigStoreResult and connect them. UDF can be included as a code or as a seperate jar included to PigLoad component.

Step by step instruction can be found here: https://www.evernote.com/l/AJONeXS0_sBNwpDfmPByJSUVS0vmAs04EGM

Comment: Hi @rrydziu, I want to achieve this through talend.
I have already written the code in Java UDF and the corresponding Pig.
Can you help me in achieving this through talend.

Comment: Hi, take a look at [docs](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioforBigDataComponentsReferenceGuide62EN/tPigLoad), they give you option to split your script into Pig components like Pig Load (with additional JAR which you can register) and Pig Code where you can transform data from one schema into another and finally PigStoreResult to save data. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: hi @rrydziu,can you please create a demo job and help me as I am new to the big data part of Talend and I am unable to configure it.

Comment: Which version have you used to build the job. I am using 6.1.1 and when I am trying to import your job, it's not getting imported due to version mismatch.

Comment: Also I tried dowloading the free tool of 6.2 from https://www.talend.com/download/talend-open-studio and the TOS is not running. Can you please guide on this or make the job in 6.1.1 if possible.

Comment: sorry, I've used latest version, I can't download older version. I've created step by step instruction here: https://www.evernote.com/l/AJONeXS0_sBNwpDfmPByJSUVS0vmAs04EGM .

Comment: hi @rrydziu I did the steps that you have provided, but I am getting the below error:
Execution failed : Failed to generate code.
[org.eclipse.emf.codegen.jet.JETException: InvocationTargetException in Data_type_pig job]
Can you please help

Comment: Also, I tried to debug the error and found that when we change the tPigLoad configurations to 'Local' the code doesn't get generated and if we have distribution to Amazon EMR,the code gets generated, but then I get the below errror:
[ERROR]: org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell - Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
Can you help on this.

Comment: so the second error is related to lack of HADOOP_HOME env on your Windows station - **null** in your case. You can find compiled for Hadoop 2.7.1 [here](https://github.com/karthikj1/Hadoop-2.7.1-Windows-64-binaries). 
For JETException you should check talend logs, nice tips you can find [here](https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=4560) - Maybe some libs are missing for local run. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Did you get the same JETException error when you compiled on your local.

Comment: Ohh...So if I run the job on a system which has Hadoop home set up, it should run fine or else I have to completed the steps that you have mentioned above.

Comment: Hadoop_home is required if you want to use haadop libraries, for example hadoop client for uploading files, or scheduling job in yarn. In your case you wanted to schedule a job to Amazon EMR which may require some additional libraries. For local run you only need Pig which doesn't require Hadoop to run when 'local' is set (pig -x local).

Comment: @rryduiz : thanks for the help. This almost completes my requirement, but the added requirement is if I want to do this trasnformation on multiple columns in a single iteration and split the respective columns into two columns how can I do it. For Example: col1 and col2 at the same time. How can I achive the same.

Comment: I think it's more a Pig question then, not Talend. I would suggest creating a new question and someone will help. This question is related to splitting your task into Talend. I'm not sure what you want to achieve with this Pig script and UDF - can you elaborate about that with example input and expected output?

Comment: In the job i just want the facility to add more than one column to be split. If that's not possible in Talend I can check how I can do it in Pig UDF.

Comment: you can use STRSPLIT to split strings in as many columns as you want. It will create bag for you. You can read full example [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_pig/apache_pig_strsplit.htm). But I'm not sure what you want to achieve. You weren't splitting anything in your code. Provide example input and expected output.

Comment: I don't have to split anything, what I want is if there are two columns that need to be used in my UDF code, can I achieve the same. Now the current code works on one column, what I want is to work on multiple columns.

Comment: so your UDF works on tuple, you can access all columns from there - modify UDF.

Comment: I have accepted your solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @rryduiz: one small issue that i have come up with is how can i populate the output tuple into two columns. I want the record that is coming in a single tuple with delimiter to be put into two columns. How can I modify the job to achieve this.

Comment: I don't understand - can you show example input tuple and expected output tuple? Is it tuple with 1 item/column - (single_tuple_value_with;delimiter) -> (single_tuple_value_with , delimiter ) - tuple with 2 "columns"/items ?

Comment: What I meant was my output tuple brings only one column.For example if i have a value as 'aab123' then the output tuple in from my code would give me the value as 'aab,123' in a single column. Can you help me to split the same into two output columns in Talend.

Comment: @rryduiz: is my example clear of the requirement. Do let me know if any clarification is needed.

Comment: @user3454116 , take a look at schema link in pigcode element ![schema link in pigcode element](http://i.imgur.com/Y63S6oN.png) , you can specify what is the input schema (columns/elements in tuple) and what is the output schema ![schema](http://i.imgur.com/rNU8Rjd.png). Hope it helps.

Comment: @rryduiz: but here the input and and output schema is defined manually.
But how do I split the one output tuple into two columns. As I have shown in my comment that the output column will have value like 'aab,123'. How do i put it into two output columns.

Comment: when you run PigCode you specify names of elements in tuple and it is mapped to schema that is defined in talend.

    FOREACH A GENERATE $0 as col1, $1 as col2, $2 as col3,$3 as col4, $4 as col5, $6 as col6;

So if you have tuple element with comma you just split it and GENERATE it as two elements which maps to 2 columns.

Comment: @rryduiz: Does this mean that from my input file where i had 5 columns in the input out of which in one column i had 'aab123' and four random values in four other columns , I would get six column where column 1 will have 'aab' and column 2 will have '123' and the other four columns will have the other four random values. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @rryduiz: is my understanding correct or i have to make any other change in my code.

Comment: Hi! yes, if in generate line you will split aab123 into two named fields using some magic function like strsplit or substring. it is Pig logic code. In talend you only specify the schema. In my opinion talend schema is not super important here, it is only required when you want to use other Pig components provided by Talend like Pig Column Filter. You could do everything with 3 components: PigLoad, PigCode and PigStore and you can probably ignore schema.